# How to know the Direction of the Acceleration Vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems

If the exercise doesn't give you the direction, how to know the correct one? Sometimes I assume its to the right and it was actually to the left, and I get everything wrong. Example here:

[image]

How can I know which direction the acceleration vector points at? Downward or upwards?

Comment: What? I have no clue what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the picture, I guess. Have you read [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)? Is the mass supposed to be oscillating, or is it just hanging there? You are not giving enough information to even remotely grasp what your problem really is.

Comment: the mass is oscillating , problem is : is it T-P=ma or P-T=ma?

Comment: Do you know [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hookes_law)? Do you know [Newton's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtons_laws)? If yes, what's the problem exactly? If no, try to understand these first.

Comment: You _assume_ a positive direction for displacement, velocity and acceleration and if the result is negative then the result is in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the drawing you give, it appears that the 'down' direction is the direction of *positive* displacement, i.e., the $x$ unit vector points towards the bottom of the page.

Thus, a *positive* acceleration $a = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is towards the bottom of the page in the direction of *increasing* $x$.

If you calculate a negative value for $a$, you know the acceleration is towards the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration always points in the same direction as the force. That's because Newton's second law tells us that:

$$ \vec{F} = m\vec{a} $$

where the force $\vec{F}$ and the acceleration $\vec{a}$ are both vectors.

So to work out which direction the acceleration is just ask which direction the force is. In the example you've given consider whether the total force is pulling the mass up or pulling it down, and the acceleration will point in the same direction.